# Gave Apple SSD disk password after selling. Is my security compromised?

Tags: icloud, security, ssd, password, data

I follow steps 4, 7 and 8 (I think...) [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065) for a Macbook Pro 13 Late 2013 in order to sell it. I would like to know if my security is compromise for not doing steps 5, 6 and possibly 8. Asking since the buyer just reached out asking for the password to unlock the disk ([image: Apple SSD - Data]) and I gave it to him since I thought it was needed for him to use the computer.

Additional questions may be: Can he access my iMessage? Can he access the data I had?

Sorry if I'm being paranoid and just asking stupid questions. Dealing with this is hard for my anxiety.

Comment: Which specific password did you share, the one for the user account on your old Mac, or the Apple ID password?

Comment: The one for the user on the old Mac. I didn't share the one I use to access my iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a FileVault password to un-encrypt the disk.

If you erased the disk before you sold it, then you should be fine.

However, I would recommend that you tell the buyer to wipe the disk in Recovery mode and reinstall the OS. Then they can configure the security and passwords as they want, and satisfy themselves that they have a 'clean' OS.

Comment: @ed1123 Also, if you used the same password for other accounts, you need to change all these passwords.

Comment: I wonder what happened since the mac was in out of the box state. When turned on it showed the configuration wizard after I reinstalled the OS.